# Calling a Post method of a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, dropwizard

I have a web service with 3 endpoints. as follows -

```
GET     /Game/getGameAll/ (com.service.rest.Game)
GET     /Game/getGameById/{gameId} (com.service.rest.Game)
POST    /Game/updateGame/{gameId}/{isAvailable} (com.service.rest.Game)
```

For testing I use -

```
localhost:8080/Game/getGameAll/
localhost:8080/Game/getGameById/1000
```

and it works perfectly fine.

but when executing update functionality -

```
localhost:8080/Game/updateGame/1000/true
```

it gives me an error 404: method not found.

But if i change the annotation from post to get. It executes.

```
//@POST  : If this is changed to Get, it works! But not with @POST. 
@GET
@Path(value = "/updateGame/{gameId}/{isAvailable}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Game updateGame(
    @PathParam(value = "gameId") Integer gameId,
    @PathParam(value = "isAvailable") int isAvailable) { .. 
.
}
```

How can i execute the Post method of a webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying this from your web browser? You won't be able to call POST methods that way.

You can either use [curl](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) from your command line or an interactive client such as [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/).